# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
when i used command catkin make to build my project workspace first_robot_ws using ros Kinetic Kame on ubuntu 16.04
that was the outbut

note that i am installing anaconda3 on my laptop

```
    abdullah@Hamo:~/first_robot_ws$ catkin_make
    Base path: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws
    Source space: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/src
    Build space: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build
    Devel space: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/devel
    Install space: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/install
    ####
    #### Running command: "cmake /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/src 
    -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/devel -
     DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in
    "/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build"
     ####
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
    `enter code here`- - The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/abdullah/anaconda3/bin/python (found version "3.5.2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/abdullah/anaconda3/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /home/abdullah/anaconda3/bin/nosetests
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/abdullah/anaconda3/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/abdullah/first_robot_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244007/invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [Abdullah Aml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28018/abdullah-aml/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-09-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem by

1- uninstall ROS

2- i uninstalled anconda3

3- I typed `sudo nano .bashrc` to clear anaconda as my main python  so i cleared every path related to ROS and anconda3

4- i installed ROS again

when i do catkin_make again i works

---

Originally posted by [Abdullah Aml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28018/abdullah-aml/) with karma: 66 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-09-22**:
oh, sorry for coming too late to help. so, you didn't have to uninstall ROS nor anaconda, just remove anaconda from the path. Enjoy ROS now with bit clearer situation.

**Comment by [JudeVR](https://answers.ros.org/users/71502/judevr/) on 2021-03-05**:
How do I clear the path or change my main python.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the problem is that you are missing catkin_pkg for python. And since you are using anaconda, make sure to install it for anaconda python, and not your system python. (from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html) I would say it is *conda install*... )

(when installing as a system package, it would be *apt-get install ros-kinetic-catkin*, or with pip, *pip install catkin_pkg*, as advised [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/user_guide/installation.html))

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdullah Aml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28018/abdullah-aml/) on 2016-09-20**:
when i do sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
the package was already exits

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-09-20**:
yes, it might be so, because with apt-get you are installing for your system python. either install for anaconda python, or - my suggestion if you are just beginning and don't care much about which python to use - use you system python to work with ros.

**Comment by [Abdullah Aml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28018/abdullah-aml/) on 2016-09-20**:
tell me please, how i can do so

**Comment by [peykaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/59120/peykaf/) on 2020-09-07**:
How can we install for anaconda please ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What worked for me:

create a conda environment, activate it and `pip install catkin_pkg`. You probably need to install other required Python packages like `nose`. Then remove the build folder, as the Python PATH seems to be cached there `rm -rf ./build`.
`catkin_make` should work then

---

Originally posted by [Jarno](https://answers.ros.org/users/29984/jarno/) with karma: 31 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3